# I'm doing this the hard way - What's the right way? And why does it echo out FOUR times?

Tags: php, cookies, foreach

Long story short, I'm doing an assignment and I've got a cookie which I've got full of user entered data from select boxes. I'm trying to grab the information from the cookie, and if, say, for example, they select option A on all eight drop down boxes, it will echo out a sentence. If not, it just does nothing. Here's my code so far in question:

```
foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
if ($val === 'over2000') {
    foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
        if ($val ==='always') {
            foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
                if ($val ==='publicTransport') {
                    foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
                        if ($val ==='public') {
                            foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
                                if ($val ==='photoEditing') {
                                    foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
                                        if ($val ==='notSureSize') {
                                            foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
                                                if ($val ==='notSureType') {
                                                    foreach ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
                                                        if ($val ==='always') {
                                                            echo 'We recommend the Lenovo Thinkpad!<br>';
}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

SO, is there an easier way to write this out? and why does it echo the answer four times ?

Here's the array contents:

```
Array
(
    [price] => over2000
    [time] => always
    [where] => publicTransport
    [people] => public
    [for] => photoEditing
    [size] => notSureSize
    [type] => notSureType
    [Brand] => always
)
```

Comment: Why are you looping through the same array? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Letting us see the contents of the array will make it easier to answer. Try this line of code and gives the response, remove the square brackets.
[echo "<pre>"; print_r($savedCardArray); echo "<pre>"]. Also, because every loop uses the same variable names [$key, $value] they will overwrite each other. When it leaves a loop, to enter the parent loop, the key value will have skipped to where the inner loop finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
$savedCardArray = array("price"=>"over2000","time"=>"always","where"=>"publicTransport","people"=>"public","for"=>"photoEditing","size"=>"notSureSize","type"=>"notSureType","Brand"=>"always");
$vals = array("over2000","always","publicTransport"/*... and so on */);
$found =0;
foreach($vals as $neededVal){
    if(in_array($neededVal,array_values($savedCardArray)))
    {
        $found++;    
    }
}
if($found==count($vals))
    echo 'We recommend the Lenovo Thinkpad!<br>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the safest way to do it. Because in your example you do not make a match against the key. So `$data['Brand']` and `$data['time']` would both return true for `'always'`.

```
if(
    $data['price'] == 'over2000' && 
    $data['time'] == 'always' && 
    $data['where'] == 'publicTransport' && 
    $data['people'] == 'public' &&
    $data['for'] == 'photoEditing' &&
    $data['size'] == 'notSureSize' &&
    $data['type'] == 'notSureType' &&
    $data['Brand'] == 'always'
) {
    echo 'We recommend the Lenovo Thinkpad!<br>';
}
```

Considering `$data` contains your cookie-data.

Comment: This did it! I'm VERY new to PHP, and I'm aware how god awful my question is, so I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with the loop so you can expand upon this should you need to change any values;

```
$checkArray = array('over2000', 'always', 'publicTransport', 'public', 'photoEditing', 'notSureType', 'always');
$checkFlag = 0;

foreach  ($savedCardArray as $key => $val) {
    if (!in_array($val, $checkArray)) { $checkFlag = 1; }
}

if ($checkFlag == 0) { echo 'We recommend the Lenovo Thinkpad!<br>'; }
```

Any additional values to check against should be added to the `checkArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty if this is all you want:

```
$checkArray = array('over2000', 'always', 'publicTransport', 'public', 'photoEditing', 'notSureType', 'always');
if($checkArray == array_values($savedCardArray)){
    echo 'We recommend the Lenovo Thinkpad!<br>'; 
}
```